# Returning the input stream of the object that the caller already has an instance of

Tags: java

I have a design question.

I'm using the `HttpURLConnection` class to navigate a website. In order to obtain an `HttpURLConnection` instance, I have a local *getter* method. This is responsible for setting all the request properties, including possible cookies. Anyway, throughout the life cycle of this application, I use multiple `HttpURLConnection` instances. And **never** is there more than one open connection.

Anyway, I have another local method for sending requests in the form of an *HTTP POST*. Here is the code:

```
private final InputStream sendRequest(final HttpURLConnection conn, final String content){
    InputStream in = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    try{
        // Write data out to the stream
        out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream()); 
        out.writeBytes(content);
        out.flush();

        // Get the input stream
        in = conn.getInputStream();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try
        {
            if(out != null){
                out.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return in;
}
```

As you can see, as soon as I'm done writing out the content, I open an input stream on the connection and return it. The reason I do this is if I do not open the input stream on the connection, the application will hang. Therefore, I'm leaving it up to the caller as to whether or not they want to parse the incoming content. Also, the caller needs the connection instance because I leave it up to them to disconnect (that is, close the connection).

So, I guess my question is, is this a poor design? That is, opening the input stream of the connection object that the caller already has an instance of and then returning it?

Comment: You could switch to [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) where you have separate classes for building the request, executing it and handling the response. This would get rid passing around the all-in-one class that is `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Also, don't `printStackTrace()`, let `sendRequest()` throw the `IOException` if you can't handle it there. The caller has to deal with `IOException` anyway if he's going to read from the `InputStream`.

Comment: @PhilippReichart, Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use Apache's HttpClient :/. And about the `IOException`, I thought it would be friendlier if I simply caught the exception and returned `null` in the scenario where the input stream could not be opened...

Comment: Not being allowed is bad :/ Still, throw the `IOException` -- the caller has to deal with it anyway when reading and might be in a better position to handle it. Plus: Less code in `sendRequest()`. Also, properly log the exception using [JULI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html), log4j, etc. because `printStackTrace()` will cut off long stack traces and make debugging unnecessarily hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame you're not allowed to use [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/), but a little OOP may help you untangle your code.

Introduce a `ResponseHandler` interface for the caller to implement. You might also want to provide some out-of-the-box implementations in `public static` fields (if thread-safe) or via factory methods for the common cases like "give me a String" (make sure to consult the "charset" part of the response's `Content-Encoding` header when creating your `InputStreamReader`) and "give me a byte[]".

Don't supply just the `InputStream` to the `ResponseHandler` as you might need access to the response headers for character encoding, etc.

Again, this would really be much much nicer with HttpClient :/

(the following code lacks basic sanity checks for the parameters, please add them)

```
public interface ResponseHandler<T> {
    T handleResponse(HttpURLConnection conn);
}

public <T> T sendRequest(final HttpURLConnection conn, final String content,
        final ResponseHandler<T> handler)
        throws IOException {
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = conn.getOutputStream();
        // uses platform encoding, might want to explicitly
        // specify "UTF-8"
        out.write(content.getBytes());
        out.flush();

        return handler.handleResponse(conn);
    } finally {
        // closing out omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

**Edit:** If you can somehow managed to get rid of `HttpUrlConnection` in the calling code, that would be even better. Check out if you can get along with a `String` for the URL and a `Map<String, Object>` for the parameters, maybe wrap this in a `HttpRequest` object.

Answer (score 0):

Well IMHO if your class actually handled **all** the I/O with the HTTP server and returned to the caller the HTTP response body (if there was any) it would make sense.
Now the `sendRequest` method is not of much use since the caller has to deal with the HTTP and I/O  details anyway

Comment: Good point. I suppose I could write two methods: 1) sends the request, opens the input stream, but doesn't attempt to parse and 2) sends the request, opens the input stream, parses it into, let's say a `StringBuilder`, and then returns the parsed content?

Comment: I can not see why you would need the first method.You should decouple the code that handles the network part with the code that does business logic.I would suggest to extend the code to handle the HTTP transaction and send back a well defined object encapsulating the reply. This way the code that handles the HTTP is completely separated from the rest (as is the rest of the application from the I/O and network stuff).Whether the caller wants to close the connection or something else should be set as configuration parameters.This is my 1 cent opinion